# Create a string collection from unknown number of burried parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to get my head around Regex, I want to get an array of strings from a string, using the parentheses inside that string as the separator.

String example:

```
"( just some text
    ( just some text
        ( just some text )
    )
    ( just some text )
 )"
```

from the example above i should get 4 string items.

is there a way to do this using regex? the number of parentheses will be unknown per string.

Comment: You could just split on `[()]`, trim each substring and discard empty ones.

Comment: thanks i didnt think about split, i dont play around with strings much that i need to extract parts instead of the whole. still learning ^^

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Regex for this? It seems to me that this is a perfect candidate to use string's split() function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: if you use split, how do you determine the order of the strings, I just realised that i need the string collection in order like child - to - parent. maybe i should make a class or something.

Comment: I guess that would be determined by what order split handles sending the subtrings into the array. I would guess it would happened top-to-bottom, left-to-right, but I would have to look at the implementation to verify that.

All you're trying to do is get an array of substrings. I don't see a reason why you need to define a class for that.

Comment: I'll figure something out, I'm still learning, thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you must to use regular expressions this is one possible way to achieve what you ask. As others have mentioned (and using @Blorgbeard suggestion) this can easily be done with simple string Replace/Split methods also.

First replace all right parenthesis “)” characters with empty strings. Then split the string on left parenthesis “(“. This result returns a string array and some may be empty. Loop through the string array, if the string is not empty, trim it and add to a storage list. When done print the resulting storage list.

```
string data = "( just some text    (()))just some text  (just some text)    )    ((((just some text) )";

  data = Regex.Replace(data, @"\)", "");
  string[] substrings = Regex.Split(data, @"\(");
  List<string> results = new List<string>();
  string temp = "";
  foreach (string s in substrings) {
    if (s != "") {
      temp = s.Trim();
      results.Add(temp);
    }
  }
  foreach (string s in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you this is a pretty cool alternative, im new with regex and hope to get good soon. :)